# Cassandra in a container - what to do (sequence of events) to snapshot the storage volume?

Tags: cassandra

Running Apache Cassandra 3 in Docker. I need to snapshot the storage volumes. Obviously, I want to be able to re-launch Cassandra from the snapshots later on. So the snapshots need to be in a consistent state.

With most DBs, the sequence of events is this:

- flush the DB to disk
- "freeze" the DB
- snapshot the storage
- "unfreeze" the DB

What does that sequence translate to, in Cassandra parlance?

What is the sequence of events that needs to happen when I bring the DB up from an old snapshot? Will there be a restore procedure, or can I just start it as usual?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No need to do anything special. With default settings, Cassandra will sync to storage every 10 seconds. After fsync, consistency is guaranteed. So take a snapshot whenever you want, the worst that could happen is you lose 10 seconds of transactions.

If you like, you can force a sync with "nodetool flush", and then snapshot the storage. This will force an fsync ahead of time and minimizes the transaction losses. But it's not mandatory.